# Match several occurrences or zero (in this order) using regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, groovy, match, roman-numerals

I want to match roman numbers using Groovy regular expressions (I have not tried this in Java but should be the same).
I found an answer in this website in which someone suggested the following regex:

```
/M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})/
```

The problem is that a expression like `/V?I{0,3}/` is not greedy in Groovy.
So for a string like "Book number VII" the matcher `/V?I{0,3}/` returns "V" and not "VII" as it would be desired.

Obviously if we use the pattern `/VI+/` then we DO get the match "VII"... but this solution is not valid if the string is something like "Book number V" as we will get no matches...

I tried to force the maximum character catching by using a greedy quantifier `/VI{0,3}+/` or even `/VI*+/` but I still get the match "V" over "VII"

Any ideas?

Comment: It's certainly greedy in Java (running against "VIII" gives "VIII" in group 3, not "V".  Also testing just the regex `"V?I{0,3}"` also gives greedy results).  Are you sure you're observing this behaviour in Groovy?  Seems kind of surprising that Groovy would use a different regex engine.

Comment: Huh? So, `?` *is* greedy, but `{n,m}` is not?

Comment: Not exactly on topic, perhaps, but the regex seems over-specified.  It will pass invalid Roman numerals so it can't be used for error checking.  Yet it's a PITA apparently.  How about something like `[MCDXLIV]+` instead?

Comment: I just run this in Java and the results are correct. So Java returns greedy results. But Groovy does not. I am running a script using the Groovy console for groovy 1.7.0 and {0,3} is NOT greedy. The strange thing is that {n,m} IS greedy, but ONLY when n!=0. Likewise .* is greedy only when a match with 0 characters does not meet the pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just (IX|IV|V?I{1,3}|V) ?

Comment: Thanks. That works since V?I{1,3} gets a higher priority than just V. I'm just confused since V?I{0,3} should work ok by itself (and it does in Java but not in Groovy)

Comment: So.. how about picking this answer as "the one"?

Answer (score 0):

I found what my mistake was.
Thing is that patterns like `/V?I{0,3}/` or `/V?I*/` are met even by EMPTY strings... so for a string like **"Book VII"** the matcher will throw the following result matches:

```
Result[0] --> ''
Result[1] --> '' 
Result[2] --> ''
Result[3] --> '' 
Result[4] --> '' 
Result[5] --> 'VII'
Result[6] --> ''
```

The greedy result is there (Result[5]) alright.
My problem was that I was always picking the first match (Result[0]) and that is only valid if the pattern is not met by empty strings.

For instance, the suggested pattern `/V?I{1,3}|V/` will throw only one result, so picking the first result match is Ok:

```
Result[0] --> 'VII'
```

... This is so since the pattern is not met by empty strings.

Hope this helps others